ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeseriesGenerator'
I am trying to download TimeseriesGenerator from keras but i keep getting this error message below
ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeseriesGenerator' from 'keras.preprocessing.sequence' (C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\ft7206forecasting\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\sequence\__init__.py)

I installed keras and tensorflow via pip, and made sure that I downloaded the upgraded version. I am still getting the error message

Can you share your keras version? I suspect you have Keras 3 installed, however the preprocessing module is only available in Keras 2.

Please modify your code as follows:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

and it will work.
I mean import from tensorflow, not keras.
